# How to discard changes to context in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a huge list of "flattened" objects in json format, and a somewhat complicated relational DB schema (with about 20 tables corresponding to a flattened object). I'm trying to automate the insertions of those flattened objects in my new relational database:

```
foreach (var flattenedObject in flattenedObjects)
{
    _repository.Insert(flattenedObject).Wait();
    //some time logging, etc
}
```

The `Insert()` method calls`AddRangeAsync()` and `AddAsync()` for a number of related objects in different tables.

Since the flattened objects are legacy, I'd say about 0.001% of them are malformed and will violate DB constraints - for example trying to insert a duplicate composite primary key in one of the tables.

I expect these rare errors, thus my idea is - wrap the whole `Insert()` operation in a transaction - if any piece of the operation is invalid, just don't insert anything and log the error, so I can modify the flattened object manually before trying again. Thus my code looks somewhat similar to this:

```
public async Task Insert(FlattenedObject fo)
{
    using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //magical code that calls AddAsync for multiple tables
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback()
            //logging
        }
    }
}
```

However, if an error occurs somewhere in my try block (I try to insert an object that violates a composite primary key) my whole context object becomes corrupt.

The object that caused the exception still remains in my DbContext and any following call to `AddAsync()` in a different transaction triggers a new exception.

I tried recreating my DbContext and repo for every new object in the `foreach` loop above - but even then if I query:

```
_context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
```

I see my old object is still in the new instance of dbContext.

Is there any (elegant) way to tell my context to reset all pending changes - so that I can put it in the catch block whenever an error occurs? I want everything that happens within my failed transaction to stay there and not leak.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The code below worked for me. However, if someone posts a cleaner solution (I still expect there to be something out of the box with EF) I will accept it.

```
private void ResetContextState() => _context.ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.Entity != null).ToList()
    .ForEach(e => e.State = EntityState.Detached);
```

Comment: Shouldnt you include  following condition in .where(e => e.Entity!=null && e.state == EntityState.Added) before detaching

Comment: That would be true for my current scenario where an insert is causing the trouble. However someone might have a similar problem with an update, so I'll leave this answer as it is for copy+paste if someone else faces such issues.

Comment: dettaching every entity present in the context in equlent to context.Reload() , when context is used next time .This will have a huge db hit.As it is same as creating the context object again

Comment: context.Reload() is exactly what I am looking for with this question. Although, it doesn't appear to be an option with the standard EF packages for Core.

Comment: i still didnt get why you want to reload your context object again ... btw reload is available from EFCore 1.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138471/discussion-between-cpr43-and-nikovn).

Comment: @nikovn Did you end up finding a better/built in solution for this?

Comment: @MichaelTranchida Just FYI, I don't know if there's a better solution, but nikovn's solution worked perfectly for me.

Comment: On EF Core 3.1 I couldn't find a Reload option per se; however after detaching all the entries in the ChangeTracker -- using the above code -- I'm can then call context.SaveChanges() to effectively reset it (resolves and discards all those detached Entries, leaving the changes count at zero, and effectively saves zero things so no effect on the db). And then continue your use of the context.

Comment: @nikovn: why don't you set the State of the Entities to EntityState.Unchanged?

Comment: Setting the state of entities to EntityState.Unchanged, or detaching the entity doesn't work for me (perhaps as a result of the way I registered my ApplicationDbContext as transient to have the same lifetime as my services). In the meantime I have opted to also use Reload().

Answer (score 26):

### Solution :

After years, maybe some of you are still looking, and by a miracle you are using EF Core 5.0. There is a new feature to clear the ChangeTracker :

```
dbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

Just call it whenever an update fails.
**But do not forget that this is not at all the best practice.** Microsoft recommends to create new dbContext for each request, as it is designed to have that short lifespan. 
More information here : [Microsoft EF Core 5.0: ChangeTracker.Clear Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0)

### Better Solution

But bit more complexe, is to use the DbContextFactory. This can be useful when application code needs to create and dispose context instances manually.

More Information here : [Microsoft EF Core 5.0 : DbContextFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#dbcontextfactory)

Enjoy

Comment: This does not revert the changes to the context. Modified entities are not reverted, this simply detaches everything. It may be enough for what the OP needs, but it's wrong as an answer in light of the questions title.