# EF Core HasQueryFilter on Include()

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm a bit confused if the `HasQueryFilter` method should work on entities that are joined by the `Include()` method.

From this (old) article, they state the following:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/12/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-1/

> Filters are applied automatically when queries retrieve data of
>   specific types directly as well as through navigation properties, e.g.
>   using the **Include()** method.

What I have in my `DbContext` class is the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.Removed == null);
}
```

If I then execute the following, then it also retrieves all the `Posts` records where `Removed` is ***not*** null.

```
// Doesn't apply the query filter because of the Include()
var blog = _dbContext.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts).Where(x => x.Id == 100);
```

If I query `Post` directly, then the `HasQuerFilter` does its job.

```
// Here query filter works, because of query directly on Entity
var posts = _dbContext.Posts.ToList();
```

So is it correct that this functionality doesn't work (yet?) on entities that are joined using `Include()`? Or am I mising something?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (using ef-core 2.1.4). My query filter works in a similar setting.

Comment: @GertArnold I am using the InMemory provider, in a Unit Test. Not sure if that could make a difference?

Comment: O surely yes. Each db brand has its own query provider. Maybe you should check if this is a know bug [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/).

Comment: @GertArnold Found the problem. I was using just one `using` statement in my tests to create a `dbContext`, instead of two, like you can see in the docs. Appearently you ***must*** have one `using` statement where you add data to the `dbContext`, then use another `using` statement to query from. It's working fine now this way.

Comment: Well, yes. A global filter won't _detach_ entities from a context.

Comment: Sorry @Vivendi I am having the same problem and I don't understand the solution you commented. Can you explain a little more? It would be of great help. Thank you

Comment: I am still not sure how you solved this..., can you write an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with tracking (which is why multiple `using` statements works).

There are different ways to do it though:

See [How do I clear tracked entities in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423059/how-do-i-clear-tracked-entities-in-entity-framework)

We used:
`_dbContext.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Detached;`