# Entity Framework Core not updating models after a SQL Server trigger updates and a new query of the database

Tags: sql-server, caching, entity-framework-core, change-tracking

I have an issue with a model not updating to the latest version after requiring the database (probably due to change tracking?).

I add the model to the dbset and save it through the context. At this point there is a server side trigger that updates a field with a link to another table pk column.

After adding the record i need to know the value in the updated column. I requery the database, and a SQL Server trace shows that the new value is returned, but the model value is not updated.

I have tried dethatching the entities similar to [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423059/how-do-i-clear-tracked-entities-in-entity-framework) but this does not work.

I have worked around it by creating a new scope from the service scope factory and creating a second instance of my context, but would like to know why this happens and how to avoid it (I have no control of the database so I can't remove the trigger and do everything in code sadly).

Thanks

Paul

Comment: It's possible to refresh the cached object instance (or use no tracking query) to get the updated value, but isn't it better in your case to configure the property as [Value generated on add or update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#value-generated-on-add-or-update) (the documentation example is showing trigger usage similar to yours)? This way you won't need manual requery, EFC will automatically do that for you.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Ivans answer in the comments takes care of this.  anotating the property in the model with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`

takes care of everything atuomatically.

Thanks for the help